# the_tags : can we insert a class

Tags: plugins, functions, codex, tags

```
<?php the_tags( '<ul><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' ); ?>
```

when we use the above we get this kind of HTML →

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://......./tag/first-lady/" rel="tag">first lady</a></li>
<li><a href="http://........./tag/ivanka/" rel="tag">ivanka</a></li>
<li><a href="http://......../tag/sexy/" rel="tag">sexy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible that within the anchor tag we can insert a class like this →

```
<li><a href="http://........./tag/ivanka/" rel="tag" class="my_custom_class">ivanka</a></li>
```

Reference →
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
<?php
$post_tags = get_the_tags();
if ($post_tags) {
  foreach($post_tags as $tag) {
    echo '<a href="'; echo bloginfo();
    echo '/?tag=' . $tag->slug . '" class="' . $tag->slug . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
  }
}
?>
```

The code is from another answer on Stack Overflow, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314716/wordpress-adding-class-selectors-to-the-tags-output) for the source and more info